# swift Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of rangeの解決方法

Tags: swift, swiftui

この中の

```
Section(header: Text("青梅市").font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding(.top),
                        footer:
                            Text("全件")){
                    ForEach(0..<oumesi.count) { index in
                        Text(self.oumesi[index])
                    }
                }
```

このText(self.oumesi[index])の部分にエラーメッセージが出てしまい、この部分を削除してみてもほかのセクションの[index]の部分にエラーが出てしまいました。原因が全くわかりません。どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let adatiku = ["舎人公園ドッグラン"]
    let arakawaku = ["ロイヤルホームセンター南千住店ドッグラン"]
    let itabasiku = ["城北中央公園ドッグラン","ドッグカフェ小豆沢","ドッグアイランド・ベルシアン"]
    let edogawaku = ["篠崎公園ドッグラン"]
    let ootaku = ["城南島海浜公園つばさドッグラン","羽田空港ペットホテル内ドッグラン"]
    let katusikaku = ["水元公園ドッグラン"]
    let koutouku = ["辰巳の森海浜公園ドッグラン","木場公園ふれあい広場ドッグラン","イオン東雲ショッピングセンタードッグラン","ららぽーと豊洲ドッグラン","綱吉の湯ドッグラン","お台場ドックリゾートドッグラン","いーの森DogGarden","JOKER's TOWN","犬のひみつきち"]
    let sinagawaku = ["しおさいドッグラン"]
    let sibuyaku = ["代々木公園ドッグラン","代官山ドッグガーデン"]
    let sinnjyukuku = ["落合公園ドッグラン（犬の広場）","愛犬ビレッジドッグラン"]
    let setagayaku = ["蘆花恒春園ドッグラン","駒沢オリンピック公園ドッグラン","KISS Wann"]
    let taitouku = ["犬のしつけ教室　DOGLYドッグラン"]
    let tyuuouku = ["ボヌール・デ・シアン","築地川公園わんわん広場"]
    let nakanoku = ["平和の森公園ドッグラン"]
    let bunnkyouku = ["目白台運動公園わんわん広場"]
    let minatoku = ["芝浦公園ドッグラン"]
    let meguroku = ["Andy Cafe ドッグラン","室内ドッグラン Brown"]
    let akisimasi = ["カインズホーム昭島店"]
    let akirunosi = ["Wonderful Nature Village","ムラウチホビー秋川店ドッグラン"]
    let oumesi = ["カインズホームあきる野市","青梅"]
    let koganeisi = ["小金井公園ドッグラン"]
    let komaesi = ["多摩川河川敷ドッグラン"]
    let tatikawasi = ["国営昭和記念公園ドッグラン"]
    let tamasi = ["桜ヶ丘公園ドッグラン"]
    let tyouhusi = ["神代植物公園"]
    let nisitamagunn = ["みずほエコパークドッグラン"]
    let hatiouzisi = ["ムラウチホビー八王子店ドッグラン","七国公園ドッグラン"]
    let hinosi = ["日野市営ドッグラン"]
    let hussasi = ["Wesr Dog Park","DOF SMALL GARDEN koniwan"]
    let matidasi = ["カインズホーム町田多摩境店","小山内裏公園わんわん広場","野津田公園ドッグラン"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack {
            Section(header: Text("足立区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全１件")){
                ForEach(0..<adatiku.count) { index in
                    Text(verbatim: self.adatiku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("荒川区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<arakawaku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.arakawaku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("板橋区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<itabasiku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.itabasiku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("江戸川区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<edogawaku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.edogawaku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("大田区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<ootaku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.ootaku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("葛飾区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<katusikaku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.katusikaku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("江東区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<koutouku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.koutouku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("品川区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<sinagawaku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.sinagawaku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("荒川区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<sibuyaku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.sibuyaku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("新宿区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<sinnjyukuku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.sinnjyukuku[index])
                }
            }
            }
            VStack {
            Section(header: Text("世田谷区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<setagayaku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.setagayaku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("台東区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<taitouku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.taitouku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("中央区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<tyuuouku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.tyuuouku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("中野区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<nakanoku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.nakanoku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("文京区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<bunnkyouku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.bunnkyouku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("港区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<minatoku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.minatoku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("目黒区").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<meguroku.count) { index in
                    Text(self.meguroku[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("昭島市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<akisimasi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.akisimasi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("あきる野市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<akirunosi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.akirunosi[index])
                }
            }
                Section(header: Text("青梅市").font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding(.top),
                        footer:
                            Text("全件")){
                    ForEach(0..<oumesi.count) { index in
                        Text(self.oumesi[index])
                    }
                }
                
            }
            VStack {
            Section(header: Text("小金井市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<koganeisi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.koganeisi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("狛江市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<komaesi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.komaesi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("立川市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<tatikawasi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.tatikawasi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("多摩市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<tamasi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.tamasi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("調布市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<tyouhusi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.tyouhusi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("西多摩郡").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<nisitamagunn.count) { index in
                    Text(self.nisitamagunn[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("八王子市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<hatiouzisi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.hatiouzisi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("日野市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<hinosi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.hinosi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("福生市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<hussasi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.hussasi[index])
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("町田市").font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top),
                    footer:
                        Text("全件")){
                ForEach(0..<matidasi.count) { index in
                    Text(self.matidasi[index])
                }
            }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: 本文中のコード部分の先頭と最後に ``` だけの行を入れておくことにより、その分がコードとして書式化されます。今後も当サイトを利用される場合には、覚えておいてください。また、今回のご質問内容については swiftui タグを指定された方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

あなたがコード中で使われている`ForEach(半開範囲)`の構文は固定した範囲に対するViewを計算するためのものです。

[init(_:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6db7u)

> Creates an instance that computes views on demand over a given **constant range**.

何の変化に対してどう固定でなければいけないのかまではドキュメントに明記されていないので、このような使い方で`Index out of range`になってしまうのは、SwiftUIのバグといってしまっても良いかもしれないのですが、とにかくご質問のようなコードについてはうまく動かないことが知られています。

すべての`ForEach`を`id:`パラメータのあるイニシャライザ(`init(_:id:content:)`)に置き換えてみてください。

```
                    ForEach(0..<oumesi.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text(self.oumesi[index])
                    }
```

(他の`ForEach`も全て同様。)

---

現在のあなたのコードはほとんど同じことが繰り返されており、この程度の修正でも大変な手間がかかりますね。データ構造を工夫してコードを簡略化できないか工夫して見るべきでしょう。